# Simple Javascript array of 4 integers that holds the following numbers: 12,14,16 and 18

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, addition

How could I create dynamic array that start in 12 and increase by 2 until 18

Here is what I tried:

```
var vec = new Array(4);
vec[0] = 12;

for (var i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
    //...
    document.write("<br/>" + vec[i]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might help  you understand how to frame a question to make it easier for people to understand and therefore help you. As it stands, your question heading is not consistent with the code you have written, so the question is really unclear (it could get deleted because of that if it gets downvoted). You can go back and edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code for creating dynamic array in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vec = new Array();
var startVar = 12;
var endVar = 18

for (var i = startVar; i <= endVar; i=i+2) {
    vec.push(i);
}
document.write("<br/>" + vec);
```

OUTPUT will be 12,14,16,18

Answer (score 0):

```
var vec = new Array(4);
var a = 12;

for (var i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
vec[i] = a + (2 * i );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An ES6 solution using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
let res = Array.from({
  // define the array length
  length: 4
    // iterate and generate array element based on index
}, (value, index) => 12 + index * 2);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// use literals for arrays and dictionaries
const vec = [];

// since you know your start and end values,
// use those in your for loop
for (let i = 12; i <= 18; i += 2) {
  vec.push(i);
}

console.log(vec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all! I also did that:

```
function range(startVar, endVar) {
    var vec = [];
    for (var i = startVar; i <= endVar; i += 2) {
        vec.push(i);
    }
    return vec;
}
var vec = range(12, 18);
document.write(vec);
```